# Best way to handle Solidity's `uint256` in ink!

Tags: ink, smart-contract, wasm, solidity

I have been working on creating a guide to port Solidity smart contracts to ink! smart contracts. I was hoping for some input on how to best handle Solidity's `uint256` in ink!.

Solidity is optimized for 256 bit / 32 byte words. So, many Solidity smart contracts use `uint256` as a way to save on gas (but not necessarily storage). ink! does not have a `u256` built in. To me, it seems like the size of a `u128` (largest primitive numerical type in ink!) would be more than sufficient to represent most non-hash numerical values.

So, I am thinking that the proper route for this is to reduce the `uint256` to a more appropriate size in ink!. Or if absolutely necessary, create a wrapper around a `[u64; 4]`.

Does this seem like an appropriate approach? Also, are there any similar word-size optimizations for ink! / Wasm?

Answer (score 3):

Answer from [@alexander-theißen](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/users/16/alexander-thei%C3%9Fen):

> The biggest primitive type in wasm is 64bit cause this is what real
> computers have (ignoring simd stuff). So there is no value in using
> u128 over a collection.